# How to access variables in lambda function? (c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I'm new to cpp, so this may seem trivial, but I want to change local variable (bool done1) in lambda function, but it seems like it's not doing anything to the varialbe and it's still true. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
    bool done1 = true;
    bool done2 = true;
    bool done3 = true;

    // associates each point to the nearest center
    std::thread thread_1([this](vector<Point> points,bool done) {
        for(int i = 0; i < total_points/3; i++) {
            int id_old_cluster = points[i].getCluster();
            int id_nearest_center = getIDNearestCenter(points[i]);
            if (id_old_cluster != id_nearest_center) {
                if (id_old_cluster != -1){
                    clusters[id_old_cluster].removePoint(points[i].getID());
                }
                points[i].setCluster(id_nearest_center);
                clusters[id_nearest_center].addPoint(points[i]);
                done = false;
            }
        }
    },points, done1);
```

Comment: Capture it by reference? Right now you are just passing it as an argument, by value which means you only have a copy of it.

Comment: Some programmer dude right. It has nothing to do with lambda.
you want to have
`[this](vector<Point> points,bool &done)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok. I tried it before, but It seems like there is problem somewhere else in the code. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change `done1` in your thread, lambda should take `bool` by reference, and  `done1` must be wrapped into `reference_wrapper` when thread ctor is called:

```
std::thread thread_1([this](vector<Point> points,bool& done) { // take by reference
    for(int i = 0; i < total_points/3; i++) {
        int id_old_cluster = points[i].getCluster();
        //...
            done = false;
        }
    }
},points, std::ref(done1) ); // <--- std::ref
```

Another option is to capture `done1` by reference, then lambda takes only one parameter:

```
[this,&done1](vector<Point> points) {
   //...
   done1 = true;
}, points);
```

Your lambda modifies vector of points, but now it is copy, so passed vector is not affected when thread ends. You need to pass points also by reference:

```
std::thread thread_1([this](vector<Point>& points,bool& done) { // both args by ref
        for(int i = 0; i < total_points/3; i++) {
            int id_old_cluster = points[i].getCluster();
            //...
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }, std::ref(points), std::ref(done1) ); // <--- std::ref 2x
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to do that in the portion of code you have just presented.

If you try to capture by reference you might get out of scope with your variable.

In order for this not to happen you will need to add an extra `thread_1.join()`
in the same scope as `bool done1 = true;`

But in this situation, your execution on the other thread will block your current thread.

You can also use other methods of synchronization like events, or simulate events with a mutex and a condition variable.

```
event x;
bool a;
thread x([&a](){ a = true; x.set(); } );
x.wait();
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/event-class?view=vs-2017

One more thing that can happen is the value can be cached. I would recommend using std::atomic when sharing variables on multiple threads.